# Proof of an equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Show that

$(1+r)(-(1+r)^{-1}-(1+r)^{-2}-...-(1+r)^{-T+1})'_r = \frac {1+r}{r^2} (1 - \frac{Tr+1}{(1+r)^{T}} )$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $(1+r)(-(1+r)^{-1}-...-(1+r)^{-T+1})'_r=(1+r) (...)'_r$ and here, instead of "..." maybe I can use the geometric progression or something like that. Then, find the derivation of (...) and get the answer? But actually I do not know how to continue this equality.

Comment: Yes, go for it!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+r)(-(1+r)^{-1}-(1+r)^{-2}-...-(1+r)^{-T+1})'_r$$$$ = -(1+r)((1+r)^{-1}+(1+r)^{-2}+...+(1+r)^{-T+1})'_r$$$$=-(1+r)(\frac{(1+r)^{-1}(1-(1+r)^{-T+1})}{1-(1+r)^{-1}})'_r$$$$=-(1+r)(\frac{1-(1+r)^{-T+1}}{r})'_r$$$$=-(1+r)(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{(1+r)^{-T+1}}{r})'_r$$$$=-(1+r)(-\frac{1}{r^2}-\frac{r \cdot (-T+1)(1+r)^{-T} - (1+r)^{-T+1}}{r^2})$$$$=\frac{1+r}{r^2}(1+r \cdot (-T+1)(1+r)^{-T} - (1+r)^{-T+1})$$$$=\frac{1+r}{r^2}(1-\frac{r\cdot(T-1)+1+r}{(1+r)^{T}})$$$$=\frac{1+r}{r^2}(1-\frac{r\cdot T+1}{(1+r)^{T}})$$

Comment: I just used the fact that $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$